# PHP statement is not evaluating to what I was expecting

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<?php

$starting_id = 0;

$params = array ('val' => $starting_id);

echo parse_params ($params);

function parse_params ($params)
{
    $query = ' WHERE ';
    if ($params['val'] === NULL) {
        $query .= ' IS NULL';
        return $query;
    }
    if ($params['val'] == 'NOT NULL') {
        $query .= ' IS NOT NULL';
        return $query;
    }    
    return $query.' = '.$params['val'];
}
```

When I run it, I expect to see this:

```
WHERE
```

instead, I get the following:

```
WHERE IS NOT NULL
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Because [`'any string' == 0`](http://codepad.org/uodDERp4) is true, you need to do a typesafe check here as well

Comment: Use `empty`  if you want to check 0 and null. http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php `The following things are considered to be empty:

"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the PHP type comparison tables,

```
$var = 0 ; // (int)
```

if you compare `$var == "string"`,

it will return `true`, you need to type check for this

```
$var === "string"
```

check php type [comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: OK, that solved the problem